# How do I add an HDRI texture environment node?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, hdri

How do I add a texture environment node in cycles?

Answer (score 2):

In the world section of the properties panel choose Surface > Use Nodes.

Select Surface: Background.

As color choose  Environment texture.

And choose the HDR image you want to use.

[image]

Or you can use the Node editor. Enable Use Nodes and in the shader editor and set it to world to add an environment texture node and connect it to a background node and then to the surface of the world output.

[image]