# Environmental Texture (HDRI Background) not Rendering in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

I am trying to make a Minecraft Animation using Cycles Render. Everything is fine, but when I try to render or animate the animation, the background is empty or black.

[image: Rendered + Environmental Texture Settings]
[image: Render Layers]

The only nodes that I used for the environmental texture are the 3 default ones, texture coordinate, and mapping (to move the background down and rotate a bit so that the sun would align with the HDRI image).

[image: NODE EDITOR]

I have used this image before on other animations, and this is the first time this had happened. One thing that is different is the Blender version, but other than that everything is the same (file location / name, image location / name, etc.).
The regular image and camera settings are shown below.

[image: Camera View + Render Settings]
[image: Camera Settings]

If anybody knows how to resolve this problem, help would be gladly appreciated!

Comment: Hey, can you attach the .blend with https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ (and edit it into your question)? That would be the fastest way to help you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I add an hdri texture environment node background?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96325/how-do-i-add-an-hdri-texture-environment-node/96326#96326) and [How can I render an object with an hdr background?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81007/how-can-i-render-an-object-with-an-hdr-background/81011#81011)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you replace your diffuse shader with a background shader it should work.

[image: This is how it should look like.]